# A Simple Photo Album with Pinch and Zoom using FlipView

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5

I'm trying to create a simple photo album (Windows Store App) using Flip View.

I have the Image element embedded within a ScrollViewer. I'm able to browse through the photos, but I'm looking to do the following things.

- The image should fill the height of the screen uniformly [when the image is not zoomed]. I get vertical scrollbars for few items. I dont have this problem when the height of all the images are the same.
- When I change the orientation of the screen, a part of the image is clipped on the right side.
- The scrollviewer should forget the zoom level (reset zoom factor to 1) when I move between pages.

This is the code I have right now. What Am I doing wrong? And what should I add in my EventHandler to reset my ScrollViewer's zoom factor.

```
<FlipView 
    Name="MainFlipView"
    Margin="0"
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
    Background="Black">
         <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ScrollViewer Name="myScrollViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled"
                                Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                MinZoomFactor="0.5"
                                MaxZoomFactor="2.5"
                                Margin="0" >
                       <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}"
                              Name="MainImage" Stretch="Uniform" />
                  </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What [user2199147](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2199147/user2199147) said should solve your first bullet point, the other two I had to fix programmatically, though it should be noted that I also had to use the `VisualTreeHelper` class which you'll have to import, and an extension method to help me use the helper class.

First of all, I had to a method from the `VisualTreeHelper` extension, which finds the first element in the `FlipView` that is of any type:

```
private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parentElement != null)
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**For going into portrait mode**, I added a callback handler for `WindowSizeChanged`, and simply reset all the `ScrollViewer`s in the flip view back to their default

```
private void WindowSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Reset scroll view size
    int count = MainFlipView.Items.Count;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var flipViewItem = MainFlipView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex((i));
        var scrollViewItem = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ScrollViewer>(flipViewItem);
        if (scrollViewItem is ScrollViewer)
        {
            ScrollViewer scroll = (ScrollViewer)scrollViewItem;
            scroll.Height = e.Size.Height; //Reset width and height to match the new size
            scroll.Width = e.Size.Width;
            scroll.ZoomToFactor(1.0f);//Zoom to default factor
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your constructor you need `Window.Current.SizeChanged += WindowSizeChanged;` in order for the callback to ever be called.

**Now, for setting each `ScrollViewer` back to their default positions**, we do a similar process, only whenever the `FlipView` selection is changed, we reset the `ScrollViewer` back to its default zoom factor

```
private void FlipViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is FlipView)
    {
        FlipView item = (FlipView)sender;
        var flipViewItem = ((FlipView)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(((FlipView)sender).SelectedIndex);
        var scrollViewItem = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ScrollViewer>(flipViewItem);
        if (scrollViewItem is ScrollViewer)
        {
            ScrollViewer scroll = (ScrollViewer)scrollViewItem;
            scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
            scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
            scroll.ZoomToFactor(1.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

And again, we have to have a call in the constructor that looks like `MainFlipView.SelectionChanged += FlipViewSelectionChanged;`

I know these methods seem really hackish and roundabout, because they are, but it's what worked for me, and I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. But even with this in the FlipView,  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}" I had to set the new Height and Width in WindowSizeChanged Event Handler.

Comment: Ahh, yeah. I had that problem too. I'm not super familiar with the Windows 8 API and such, so most of what I've done is pretty hackish.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the height and width bindings from the scrollviewer to the image.

```
<FlipView 
    Name="MainFlipView"
    Margin="0"
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
    Background="Black">
         <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ScrollViewer Name="myScrollViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled"

                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                MinZoomFactor="0.5"
                                MaxZoomFactor="2.5"
                                Margin="0" >
                       <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}"
                                      Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      Name="MainImage" Stretch="Uniform" />
                  </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good practice for WinRT is:

**1) Make Attached Property for ScrollViewer, which will change ZoomFactor**

```
public class ScrollViewerExtension : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerZoomFactorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ScrollViewerZoomFactor", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollViewerExtension), new PropertyMetadata(default(double), OnZoomFactorChanged));

    public static void SetScrollViewerZoomFactor(DependencyObject element, double value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ScrollViewerZoomFactorProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetScrollViewerZoomFactor(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (double)element.GetValue(ScrollViewerZoomFactorProperty);
    }

    private static void OnZoomFactorChanged(DependencyObject depObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (depObject is ScrollViewer)
        {
            var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)depObject;
            var zoomValue = (double)args.NewValue;
            if (!Double.IsNaN(zoomValue))
                scrollViewer.ZoomToFactor((float)zoomValue);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("ARE YOU KIDDING ME ? ITS NOT SCROLLVIEWER");
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Changer FlipViewItem Template**

```
<Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Width="1040">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  MaxZoomFactor="4"
                                  MinZoomFactor="1"
                                  Tag="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                                  ZoomMode="Enabled"
                                  extension:ScrollViewerExtension.ScrollViewerZoomFactor="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedToZoom}}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**3) Create converter, which will change ScrollViewerZoomFactor to default value if item isnt selected.**

```
public class IsSelectedToZoomConverter :DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var val = (bool) value;
        return val ? Double.NaN : 1.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**4) FlipView code will look like this:**

```
<FlipView x:Name="FlipView"
          Grid.Row="5"
          Width="1040"
          MinHeight="392"
          MaxHeight="600"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentSession.Photos}"
          Visibility="{Binding CurrentSession.HasContent,
                               Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
  <FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid Width="1040">
              <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            MaxZoomFactor="4"
                            MinZoomFactor="1"
                            Tag="{Binding IsSelected}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                            ZoomMode="Enabled"
                            extension:ScrollViewerExtension.ScrollViewerZoomFactor="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                                                             Path=IsSelected,
                                                                                             Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedToZoom}}">
                  <ContentPresenter />
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

    </FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="{Binding Path=Path}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you have a ScrollViewer within you FlipViewItemTemplate?
Thie template will be used for each Item, so for each Image you add to your ItemList.
that said it shoud be enough to have the Image element within your Template.
this should at least avoid the scrollbars for images that are bigger than your screen, cause then the Stretch="Uniform" should handle the resizing...

Comment: in that case how do i handle zoom?